# unbound module in OCaml / dune build

Tags: ocaml, opam, ocaml-dune

I trying out OCaml for the first time and trying to build a couple files together.

When I run:

```
dune build bin/main.exe
```

I am getting:

```
    ocamlc bin/.main.eobjs/main.{cmi,cmo,cmt} (exit 2)
(cd _build/default && /usr/bin/ocamlc.opt -w @a-4-29-40-41-42-44-45-48-58-59-60-40 -strict-sequence -strict-formats -short-paths -keep-locs -g -bin-annot -I bin/.main.eobjs -I lib/.lib.objs -no-alias-deps -opaque -o bin/.main.eobjs/main.cmo -c -impl bin/main.ml)
File "bin/main.ml", line 10, characters 17-25:
Error: Unbound module Rule
```

Here is my bin/main.ml file:

```
open Lib

let () =
    let result = Math.add 2 3 in
    print_endline (string_of_int result);
    let result = Math.sub 3 1 in
    print_endline (string_of_int result);
    let result = Zoom.barf 3 1 in
    print_endline (string_of_int result);
    let result = Rule.add 3 1 in
    print_endline (string_of_int result);
```

in lib/inner/rule.ml, contains:

```
let add x y = x + y
let sub x y = x - y
```

so I think I need to import the rule.ml file somehow in the `bin/main.ml` file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Dune, currently the default is that modules in different directories are not visible to each other. This is controlled by the `(include_subdirs no)` stanza ( https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dune-files.html#include-subdirs ). With this setting, to make your modules visible to each other, you need to put a `dune` file with the correct contents in each subdirectory. If you look at how the Dune project itself does it ( https://github.com/ocaml/dune ), your directory structure would look like this:

```
myproj/
  bin/
    dune
    main.ml
  lib/
    dune
    inner/
      dune
      rule.ml
```

The various `dune` files should contain the correct `(library ...)` ( https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dune-files.html#library ) or `(executable ...)` ( https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dune-files.html#executable ) stanzas, as needed.

Edit: after doing the above, you also need to refer to the `Rule` module by its full 'path', i.e. `Lib.Inner.Rule`.

Comment: so I would call `open Lib.Inner.Rule` in bin/main.ml right?

Comment: @AlexanderMills it's generally recommended to avoid `open`ing modules and instead refer to them by name. If the name is long it's recommended to alias a shorter name in as small a scope as possible, e.g. `let () = let module Rule = Lib.Inner.Rule in ...`

Comment: thanks, I am having trouble with the `bin/dune` file .. I have this `(executable
  (name main)
  (libraries lib))` but I believe I need to reference the `inner` library too

Comment: ok I got it working with `(executable
  (name main)
  (libraries lib inner))` thanks